# avoiding clear text password login for github3.py

Tags: github3.py

From a post on another stackoverflow, the following was recommended.
Is there a way to avoid using cleartext, maybe supply an existing admin ssh key instead?

```
from github3 import login
g = login('abcd', password)
with open('~/.ssh/temp.k.pub', 'r') as fd:
    key = g.create_key('abcd', fd)

print("Created {0}".format(key.title))`
```

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear, when communicating with GitHub's API, your communications are secured over HTTPS. github3.py uses requests which performs certificate verification and properly secures the connection. That said when we authentication using basic authentication, you're sending your credentials in the headers after base 64 encoding (which is not encryption and is not secure if it is *somehow* intercepted).

So really, you need to consider who you're worried about "seeing" your credentials. If you're worried about your company running a proxy locally that is meant to man-in-the-middle your connection and steal your credentials that's a good use for a limited token. You can create the token via the API or via the web UI. Either way, you would then (instead of using the code you have) do the following:

```
g = login(token='myspecialtoken')
```

Then you would do everything else the same way. I haven't checked if you can create ssh keys for the user with a token, but if it won't work you'll get an error about needing to use basic authentication (your username and password).

I still want to stress, though, that using your login credentials should be fine. The difficulty of intercepting that and retrieving your credentials as an arbitrary attacker is high. If you're worried about a different situation, you should definitely look more closely into the threat level.

Comment: If you store the credentials in you homedir, even if it is on a encrypted drive, a *personal access token* limits the attack vector to what you allowed that token. Especially all admin actions where GitHub asks for the master password are then excluded, so it is safer.

PS: Credentials should be separate from other config, e.g. go to "~/.netrc".

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables

ie

```
gh_login = os.environ.get('GITHUB_LOGIN')
gh_pass = os.environ.get('GITHUB_PASS')
```

Then pass these into `login`